# AChartEngine capabilities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, achartengine

I develop an mHealth application for maternal and newborn babies. As can be seen (https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151513093909365&set=a.10150478362674365.421812.731814364&type=1&theater), there is a line chart in the app that needs to have two fixed lines named "alert line" and "action line". In addition, each line will be added to the line chart should be checked with the position of alert line and action line to specify that they are in the left/right side of them. 
I am going to use AChartEngine in the app but I really need to know that:

1. Is it possible to have two static lines with fixed positions with AChartEngine?
2. Is it possible to specify the position of the new added line towards "action line" and "alert line"?

Please let me know about the above questions. If it is not possible (the mentioned requirements of the app) with AChartEngine, please suggest me the other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, just create 2 separate series of data that will define the static lines.
2. All the points you add to the datasets are in your data coordinates. It is up to you to calculate this position relative to whatever other lines.

Other options: draw the lines yourself, without using AChartEngine.

Comment: could you check my questions again?